# ExcelWriter using openpyxl engine ignoring date_format parameter

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have read quite a few answers on this, but when I run my code I don't get the same result.

I am using pandas 2.0.0 and openpyxl 3.1.2 on Python 3.9

This is a reduced example of my issue, which is that *I can't get the ExcelWriter to respect my choice of date format*. I am trying to append a new sheet to an existing Excel .xlsx file.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

filePath = 'c:\\temp\\myfile.xlsx'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filePath,mode='a',engine='openpyxl',if_sheet_exists='replace',date_format='DD/MM/YYY')

df = pd.DataFrame([datetime.date(2023,4,7)],columns=['Date'])
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Data')
writer.close()
```

The result in Excel is this:

[image]

I have explicitly set the type of the value in the dataframe to be `datetime.date`. I have tried using `datetime_format` or indeed both together but to no avail.

I have also tried `xlsxwriter` but it seems this engine does not allow appending to an existing workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the implementation of [`OpenpyxlWriter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py#L40):

```
class OpenpyxlWriter(ExcelWriter):
    _engine = "openpyxl"
    _supported_extensions = (".xlsx", ".xlsm")

    def __init__(
        self,
        path: FilePath | WriteExcelBuffer | ExcelWriter,
        engine: str | None = None,
        date_format: str | None = None,
        datetime_format: str | None = None,
        mode: str = "w",
        storage_options: StorageOptions = None,
        if_sheet_exists: str | None = None,
        engine_kwargs: dict[str, Any] | None = None,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        # Use the openpyxl module as the Excel writer.
        from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

        engine_kwargs = combine_kwargs(engine_kwargs, kwargs)

        super().__init__(
            path,
            mode=mode,
            storage_options=storage_options,
            if_sheet_exists=if_sheet_exists,
            engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs,
        )
```

To fix, add

```
date_format=date_format, 
datetime_format=datetime_format,
```

to the `super().__init__()` call:

```
        super().__init__(
            path,
            date_format=date_format, 
            datetime_format=datetime_format,
            mode=mode,
            storage_options=storage_options,
            if_sheet_exists=if_sheet_exists,
            engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs,
        )
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! If I have time, I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Great, I was just going to ask if you could submit one!